# python function that takes two arguments and connect to a jira

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I need to create a function that takes two arguments, one being a jira key. I then need to connect to jira project using that jira key. 
my pseudocode below :

```
def pullDefect (JiraKey,ComponentType):
            connect to jira project ‘JiraKey’
            low = low pids for ‘ComponentType’
            med = med pids for ‘ComponentType’
            high = high pids for ‘ComponentType’
            defectCount = [low, med, high]
            return defectCount
```

any help would be great

After further research I looked into the Python Jira Library which will allow me to authenticate and query

Comment: Take a look at the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and probably [Jira's API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials) and try to turn that pseudocode into actual Python and then edit the question when you get stuck.

Comment: ok I will give it a try....... thank you

Comment: def pull (JiraKey, ComponentType):

Answer (score 0):

You can try [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It is powerfull modul, supports cookies and ssl. "Requests is an elegant and simple HTTP library for Python, built for human beings."

```
login = 'username'
passwd = 'pa$$'
url = 'http://jira.example.com:8080/rest/api/latest/issue'
issue_key = 'HELP-2657'

def get_issue(url, issue, login, passwd):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url + '/' + issue_key, auth=(login, passwd))
    except Exception as ex:
        print 'EXCEPTION: %s ' % ex

    if r.status_code != 200:
        print 'ERROR: status %s' % r.status_code

    result = r.json()
    return result
```